# Installing PHP 7.2 thread-safe on a mac

Tags: php, thread-safety, pthreads

I'm trying to install PHP 7.2 **thread-safe** on a mac (Sierra 10.13).

I've tried:

- with homebrew, using the `--with-thread-safety` option, but it's not recognized anymore
- recompiling PHP with the `--with-tsrm-pthreads` option passed to ./configure, but failed

> brew install php72 --with-thread-safety Warning: php: this formula has no --with-thread-safety option so it will be ignored!

Any suggestion?

Comment: Can you show us the errors?

Comment: When trying to install with homebrew:

```➜  ~ brew install php72 --with-thread-safety

Warning: php: this formula has no --with-thread-safety option so it will be ignored!```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I solved installing it through [phpbrew](https://github.com/phpbrew/phpbrew).

Comment: How were you able to do this with phpbrew? 
W

Comment: I don't remember exactly which parameters I used, but you should be able to find them Googling a bit. I have 7.2.5 thread-safe on my machine. I believe I also used the option to compile from source. Take a look here https://github.com/phpbrew/phpbrew

Comment: Thanks for this comment...you helped me get php zts installed.

Answer (score 0):

Homebrew has started a migration of PHP related formulaes a while ago, so most of the parameters on most of the guides will not work anymore until someone will add support for them to the formulae.

Also, for most of the packages from now on Brew team recommends to use PECL.

You can try to build with flag `--enable-maintainer-zts` that should enable thread safety, it actually has worked out for me.

Comment: Ignore Brew for now, build PHP directly, for example like in this guide https://gist.github.com/tam5/2e06063c17de7e200040

Comment: Also Brew flag `--build-from-source` could do the trick, but i haven't used it, i have built PHP directly from source